# R raw to Hex conversion

Tags: r, pki

I am trying to take a look at how the rawToHex() function is implemented in PKI package.

I tried this:

```
> library(PKI)
Loading required package: base64enc
> PKI::rawToHex
Error: 'rawToHex' is not an exported object from 'namespace:PKI'
> PKI:::rawToHex
Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
object 'rawToHex' not found
```

I am basically trying to understand how to convert raw data to Hex representation in R. So I wanted to take a look at this.

Comment: Your issue is that the function is called `raw2hex`. At least that's what it is on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is clear: that function is not available in that package. The correct spelling is `raw2hex`

```r
> PKI::raw2hex
function (what, sep, upper = FALSE) 
.Call(PKI_raw2hex, what, if (missing(sep)) NULL else sep, upper)
<environment: namespace:PKI>
```

You can't see the source in this way because it is compiled.

Please read this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19226817/3079302).

Besides that, you can download the source code in [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PKI/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. The src seems to be C code from CRAN. Any other thoughts on how to implement raw to hex in R without importing any package? The reason I am looking at implementing it in R is as a workaround since I am seeing a compilation error in Vertica when i try to load the pki library

Comment: Sorry, no thoughts on that. However, it seems you have two more questions to post: 1) how to implement raw to hex in base R, and; 2) whatever error is that in Vertica when loading the PKI library.